# Get Master Page Gallery via CSOM

Tags: client-object-model

How to get master page gallery via CSOM so that we would support language packs / we cannot use `Lists.GetByTitle("Master Page Gallery")`.

So how to get list `"_catalogs/masterpage"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How to get Master Page gallery via Managed CSOM

Use [Site.GetCatalog method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.getcatalog%28v=office.15%29.aspx) with [ListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx) to retrieve Master Page gallery:

```
var list = context.Site.GetCatalog((int)ListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
```

> Note: SharePoint 2010 & 2013 compatible

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that method (deleted my answer)

Comment: And then of course `/_api/Web/GetCatalog(116)` will work as well

Comment: Good.. We could also use Web.GetCatalog for non-publishing and Site.GetCatalog for publishing site collections etc.